# Prove: limit of sum of sequences is sum of limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What's the shortest and easiest to remember and understand $\varepsilon$ proof for this?

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n+y_n\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }x_n+\lim _{n\to \infty }y_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume both limits exist and $\lim_\limits {n \to\infty}x_n=x,\lim_\limits {n \to\infty}y_n=y$.

This means that $\forall \varepsilon\gt0,\;\exists N_x,N_y$ such that $\forall n \gt \max(N_x,N_y)$ we have:

$|x_n-x|<\varepsilon/2$ and $|y_n-y|<\varepsilon/2$

By the [Triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) we have:

$|x_n+y_n-(x+y)|\le|x_n-x|+|y_n-y|\lt\varepsilon$

So $\lim_\limits {n \to\infty}(x_n+y_n)=x+y$.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.

After a certain point, n=n$_{1}$, the term in x$_{n}$ are close to its limit x, i.e. at most at a distance $\epsilon$ / 2 from x. 
Similarly, after a certain point n=n$_{2}$, the term in y$_{n}$ are close to its limit y,i.e. at most at a distance $\epsilon$ / 2 from y.

So, when we add two sequences, whenever we go past a certain point n = max{n$_{1}$, n$_{2}$}, the sum sequence will be at most at $\epsilon$ from x+y. And you are done.